# Error in Java constructor call

Tags: java

```
List<Object> allEmployees = new ArrayList<Object>();
 allEmployees.add(new SalariedEmployee());
 Object SalariedEmployee = allEmployees.get(0);
 allEmployees.add(new HourlyEmployee());
 Object HourlyEmployee = allEmployees.get(1);
```

Error says:

> constructor SalariedEmployee in class SalariedEmployee cannot be applied to given types; required: java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int; found no arguments; reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length.

The code in SalariedEmployee class is :

```
SalariedEmployee (String name, String afm, int salary){
    super (name,afm);
    this.name = name;
    this.afm = afm;
    this.salary = salary;
}
```

Amateur programmer here, new in the community too. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a constructor which expects three arguments, a `name`, `afm` and `salary`, so you have to give it the arguments it expects,

Comment: public static void main (String[] args){
    List<Object> allEmployees = new ArrayList<Object>();
    allEmployees.add(new SalariedEmployee(String name, String afm, int salary));
    Object SalariedEmployee = allEmployees.get(0);
    allEmployees.add(new HourlyEmployee(int hoursWorked, int hourlyPayment, String name, String afm));
    Object HourlyEmployee = allEmployees.get(1);

Comment: the error says : ')' expected

Comment: You should make your allEmployees list `List<Employee> allEmployees = new ArrayList<Employee>();` so that you don't get plain `Object` values when using the `get(int)` method

Comment: You need to pass arguments like `new SalariedEmployee("My Name", "My AFM", 10000)`, you are not declaring the method again.

Answer (score 1):

SalariedEmployee required constructor arguments, for example:

```
List<Object> allEmployees = new ArrayList<Object>();
allEmployees.add(new SalariedEmployee("someName", "AFM", 2000));
Object SalariedEmployee = allEmployees.get(0);
allEmployees.add(new HourlyEmployee(40, 20, "someOtherName", "AFM2"));
Object HourlyEmployee = allEmployees.get(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Java compiler provides default (no argument) `constructor` if no other `constructor` is specified in the class. However, if class contains any constructor (like `SalariedEmployee` in our example) then, you need to specify no argument constructor as well, if you are planning to instantiate class using that.

In your example, a 3 argument `constructor` is specified and hence, no argument `constructor` is not provided. When we try to create objects with no argument `constructor`, it shows error. To fix it, we need to add a no argument `constructor` in the class, e.g.:

```
public SalariedEmployee(){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`SalariedEmployee` needs three arguments to be instantiated. Without it and without another constructor, the code will certainly not compile.

If you're using an IDE, you should be able to get the possible constructors very easily.

On [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse), press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SPACEBAR</kbd> after writing `new SalariedEmployee` to get a view of the possible constructors. If only one is available, [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse) generates part of the code automatically.